# How to output java date format as 060115

Tags: java

I need a java class where it knows today's date and put an output return as '060115' if today's date is 06/01/2015 or June 1st, 2015.

Comment: .. and what are you having trouble with.  I assume you have attempted to google this first.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) is the first result when I google "How to output java date format as 060115". Everything you need to know is there. Please use Google or search first. If you have some code and it isn't working please add it to the question through an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **java Calendar** class to get everything about **Time** and **Date**:

```
System.out.println("0"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"0"
                         + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +"0"+
                         Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Using **String Format**:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class PrintDate {

  public PrintDate(){
     //Create this for later
     String year =String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)); //Keeping the year 2015

     //Format the date to keep it in a single String
     String date = String.format("0%d0%d%d",
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1), //Cause the Calendar has January as (0) i add +1
                Integer.valueOf(year.substring(1,4)));  //Make it from 2015 to 15 using Substring Method


     System.out.println(date);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
     new PrintDate();
  }
}
```